# deriving two step adam's method

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

So I am constructing an explicit Adam's family method with $s = 2$ at $x_0 = t_i, x_1 = t_{i+1}$. 
$$y_{i+1}=y_i+ \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}f(t,y(t))dt$$
We approximate $f$ with $P(t)$ using Newton's method
$$P(t) = f(t_i,y_i) + \frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i}(t-t_i)$$
I am having trouble integrating $P(t)$. I should get the answer to be $$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}P(t)dt=\frac{h}{2}[3f(t_i,y_i)-f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})]$$
However, when integrating, I get
$$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}P(t)dt = \frac{h}{2}[3f(t_i,y_i)-f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})] + t_i[f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)]$$
I am not sure how to handle the final term and make it zero. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating, \begin{align*}\int\limits_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}P(t)\, dt&=\left(f(t_i,y_i)t+\frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2-tt_i\right)\right)\Big|_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \\
&=f(t_i,y_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)+\frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i}\left(\frac{1}{2}(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2\right)\\
&=hf(t_i,y_i)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{-h}h^2\\
&=\frac{3h}{2}f(t_i,y_i)-\frac{h}{2}f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})\\
&=\frac{h}{2}\left(3f(t_i,y_i)-f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})\right),
\end{align*} since $t_{i-1}-t_i=-h, t_{i+1}-t_i=h.$

To see the connection between the first and second equality, observe that

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2-tt_i\right)\Big|_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}&=\frac{1}{2}t_{i+1}^2-\frac{1}{2}t_i^2-t_{i+1}t_i+t_i^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(t_{i+1}^2-2t_{i+1}t_i+t_i^2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(t_{i+1}-t_i\right)^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you get $(t-t_i)^2 = h^2$? Shouldn't it be $\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i}t - \frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i}t_i   dt = \frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i} \frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{f(t_{i-1},y_{i-1})-f(t_i,y_i)}{t_{i-1}-t_i}t_ih$ ?

Comment: I may be dumb, but how do you get $(t-t_i)^2|_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}$ from integrating the above and not what I wrote?

Comment: Went too fast, fixed!

Comment: How do you get $\frac{1}{2}t^2-tt_i \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2$

Comment: When you evaluate that quantity at the endpoints, you get terms that can be factored in that way. I’m not by a computer at moment, but I’ll answer in the morning.

Comment: @hkj447 I've edited it in!